# How do I listen for a Facebook app uninstall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When a Facebook user logins with our Facebook application we register him in our database as a member. But if, sometime in the future, the user wishes to not be a member of the application and uninstalls the app, how can I tell so we can remove him from our database? In other words, how can I learn of an uninstall so I can handle the event appropriately on our side?

Answer (score 1):

If the user deauthorizes your app, Facebook „pings” the deauthorize callback you can specify in your app settings. That gives you a chance to to deal with this event accordingly on your server.